# reaching a page from xamarin.forms inside android project

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm working on an android app with xamarin. I made tabbed pages. For the second page, i want to show the camerastream from my android camera. For that, some sample code said me I need to use a textureView inside the android part of the app, but that textureview needs to be putted on that second page. Whenever I try to reach a Stacklayout inside that Page, the following error shows up: *'Page1.camera' is inaccessible due to its protection level.*
Using *x:FieldModifier="public"* inside that stacklayout doesn't work either.

Here is the structure of my code to make it more clear

Here I make the tabbed pages:

```
MainPage = new TabbedPage
        {
            Children = {
                new MainPage(),
                new Page1(),
                new Page2()

            }
        };
```

Inside that Page1 i have this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="App4.Page1"
         Title="Licht">
<StackLayout x:Name="camera" x:FieldModifier="public" Orientation="Vertical">
</StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

And inside the MainActivity.cs i have this where i have to access the camera.

```
_textureView = new TextureView(Page1.camera);
```

And this is the structure of my app
[And this is the structure of my app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9ISG.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Using x:FieldModifier="public" inside that stacklayout doesn't work either.

I have tried `x:FieldModifier="public"`in xamarin form, even though I use  x:FieldModifier="public", the "camera" property is still private. This feature is not useful.

As far as I know there is no way to access "camera" inside MainActivity.cs in Xamarin form.

As a workaround you can design a page render for android platform and create a `TextureView` in your page render code.

[how to create a page render](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/custom-renderer/contentpage/)

> _textureView = new TextureView(Page1.camera);

BTW to initialize `TextureView` you need the object that implements the `ISurfaceTextureListener` interface at android platform.

```
 public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity,ISurfaceTextureListener
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
            TextureView textureView = new TextureView(this);
            textureView.SurfaceTextureListener = this;
            LoadApplication(new App());
        }
        public void OnSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height)
        {
            //start 
        }

        public bool OnSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture surface)
        {
            //stop 
        }

        public void OnSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void OnSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture surface)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        } 
    }
```

Please follow the `TextureView` [guide](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/other_ux/textureview/display_a_stream_from_the_camera/) for Android.

Comment: I didn't think of using a renderpage. Thanks for your help!